# Using Server 2012 r2 as Home router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, windows-server-2012-r2

What software / hardware would I need to setup a machine running server 2012 r2 as a home router? It needs to have all the features of a standard router & be able to shape & limit a users internet access, preferably with each user logging in to the network with a different username / password. It also needs to have both Wireless & Wired networking capabilities.

Thanks,
Elliot

Answer (score 1):

Windows Servers, including 2012 R2, have a feature called [Routing and Remote Access](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770798%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that you can enable.

It can do everything you asked and more.